# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Angle'. Xcode 11, Mac 10.15, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Angle'. Xcode 11, Mac 10.15, SwiftUI

```
    image
        .clipShape(rotation3DEffect( Angle, axis: (x: 15, y: 15, z: 15)))
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
        .shadow(radius: 10)
```

What value should be given as an 'Angle', I tried different ways but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass in a `Shape` to `.clipShape()`, e.g:

```
.clipShape(Circle())
```

You have to apply `.rotation3DEffect` as a separate modifier and it takes in as arguments an `Angle` and a tuple of 3 `CGFloats` like this:

```
.rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 10), axis: (15.0, 15.0, 15.0))
```

so your image should be declared like this:

```
image
    .clipShape(Circle())
    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
    .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 10), axis: (15.0, 15.0, 15.0))
    .shadow(radius: 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```swift
image
        .clipShape(rotation3DEffect( .degrees(Angle), axis: (x: 15, y: 15, z: 15)))
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
        .shadow(radius: 10)
```

Source: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-rotate-a-view-in-3d

**P.S.** assuming `Angle` is your int in question that cannot be converted to an angle, it is best to declare constants and variables in **lowercase**, i.e. it should be `angle` and not `Angle`. With more context, this usually isn't much of an issue, but in this context, it is hard to know that `Angle` is the constant or variable in question because it is capitalized.

Comment: looks like I am using this in wrong context. got one more error: Argument type 'some View' does not conform to expected type 'Shape'

Comment: Well, what is `some View`? We need some more context to help diagnose the issue. Can you show some more code regarding `some View`?